# How do I know what happens immediately after I provide my user name and password in Linux?

Tags: kernel, login, embedded

I'm using Linux on embedded platform with ARM processor and FPGA.
There's an Arch Linux Arm distro in rootfs, but probably this doesn't matter.
When I log in, I type in the username and password, and after that I usually wait for a very long time (over 10 seconds). Sometimes I get the response of "timed out after [...]" and need to log in once again.

Now, I'd like to debug the process that happens immediately after I enter the credentials. How do I know why it takes so long? What parts of the system are responsible for this?
I expect this is related to the kernel I use (I make modifications for my own education and I might have configured it wrongly), but instead of using another pre-built kernel, I would like to learn how to debug this. Most resources I find refer to complex, desktop distros and their login software, unfortunately.

Edit:
I connect to the device by serial port (USB<->UART converter) and use `picocom` to access it.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Arc but did you try to see log files like messages or audit or journal while you tried to login?

Comment: I haven't found any information about previous logins in system logs and journalctl. I think I would need some additional software or configuration to get this data collected.

Comment: no. I meant login and `tail` log files or `journalctl -xf` and open another terminal and try to login again. while that, consider the logs.

Comment: Do you log in via ssh? If so, delays of that length are often caused by the sshd attempting a reverse DNS lookup. Try setting `UseDNS no` in the sshd configuration to avoid that (and don't forget to restart sshd).